# how get php total time?

Tags: php, time

i have created work total time program in PHP - give input time - 1.30, 2.10, 1.40 and get output time - 4.80(8 hrs). but i need output time - 5.20(8.40 hrs).
Notes: 1.30+2.10+1.40=4.80(8 hrs), but i need 5.20(8.40 hrs). please help me...

Comment: Just add the extra 40 minutes. Or is there something you're not telling us?

Comment: 4.80 = 8hrs and 5.20 = 8.40 hrs? what kind of time measurement is that? einstein relativity or something?

Comment: How is exactly 4.80 the same as 8 hours, am I missing something?

Comment: I think Murugesh writes 4.80 to mean 480mins (8hrs) and 5.20 to mean 520mins (8hrs 40mins).

Answer (score 2):

1.30 + 2.10 + 1.40 is wrong. Should be:

((1 * 60) + 30) + ((2 * 60) + 10) + ((1 * 60) + 40) = 320 (minutes)

320 minutes = 5 hours and 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of minutes and seconds separately:

```
$minutes = array();
$seconds = array();
foreach ($times as $time) {
    $parts = explode('.', $time);
    $minutes[] = $time[0];
    $seconds[] = $time[1];
}
$total_minutes = array_sum($minutes);
$total_seconds = array_sum($seconds);
while ($total_seconds > 60) {
    $total_minutes++;
    $total_seconds -= 60;
}
echo $total_minutes . ' minutes and ' . $total_seconds . ' seconds';
```

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from PHP site for your pleasure:

```
function AddTime ($oldTime, $TimeToAdd) { 
  $pieces = split(':', $oldTime); 
  $hours=$pieces[0]; 
  $hours=str_replace("00","12",$hours); 
  $minutes=$pieces[1]; 
  $seconds=$pieces[2]; 
  $oldTime=$hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds; 

  $pieces = split(':', $TimeToAdd); 
  $hours=$pieces[0]; 
  $hours=str_replace("00","12",$hours); 
  $minutes=$pieces[1]; 
  $seconds=$pieces[2]; 

  $str = $minutes." minute ".$seconds." second" ; 
  $str = "01/01/2000 ".$oldTime." am + ".$hours." hour ".$minutes." minute ".$seconds." second" ; 

  if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false) { 
    return false; 
  } else { 
    $sum = date('h:i:s', $timestamp); 
    $pieces = split(':', $sum); 
    $hours = $pieces[0]; 
    $hours = str_replace("12", "00", $hours); 
    $minutes = $pieces[1]; 
    $seconds = $pieces[2]; 
    $sum = $hours.":".$minutes.":".$seconds;
    return $sum; 
  } 
} 

$firstTime  = "00:03:12"; 
$secondTime = "02:04:34"; 

$sum=AddTime($firstTime, $secondTime); 

if($sum != false) { 
  echo $firstTime." + ".$secondTime." = ".$sum; 
} else { 
  echo "failed"; 
}
```

Output:

```
00:03:12 + 02:04:34 = 02:07:46
```

Comment: This code is with a good overhead IMO, but will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For each number (represented as `$t` below) you can do this:

```
// start with $total=0
$hours = floor($t); // 1.10 -> 1 hr
$minutes = ($t - $hours) * 100; // 1.10 -> 10 mins
$total += ($hours * 60) + $minutes;
```

That gives you the total number of minutes. To get hours/mins separately, do this:

```
$total_mins = $total % 60; // 130 -> 10 mins
$total_hours = ($total - $total_mins) / 60; // 130 -> 2 hrs
```